# how to split an object into two

Tags: mesh, objects

Beginner in blender. I am trying to split an object into two equal parts by bisecting it. However whenever I try to bisect it, Blender gives me the error message, "Selected edges/faces required." What does this mean and what should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bisect tool is described in Blender online manual but there are more precise ways to do it. You select, border or circle, exactly half of the faces or, when your object is large single quads, use <kbd>Ctrl+R</kbd>, select and then separate by selection.

I write this as Bisect doesn't seem to snap to edges which is vital when you want to **halve** and object and keep faces **intact**. The idea behind the Bisect tool is just to make a cross-section and that doesn't have to mean halves.

Answer (score 5):

In *Edit* mode you need to select at least one face or one edge of your object, or the whole mesh, meaning you want to cut this face/edge/whole mesh. Then activate the *Bisect* tool. On the bottom of the *Tools* panel (on the left of the 3D View) you can enable some options. I guess the best is to leave everything as it is. Then to separate the two parts you've created, keep the cutting selected, then press <kbd>V</kbd> to rip, now you can select a half or the other with <kbd>L</kbd>. To make another object with one of your halves, select it and press <kbd>P</kbd> > *Selection*.

[image]